# How can i pass the token to my child component react native

Tags: react-native

I was having trouble with how to get and save my token in my login component to my app component that is done now, I can't log out in because I don't know how to get the token from the local storage and I don't know how to pass it to the other screen and catch it there. this is my app component :

```
const App = () => {
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value) => {
      if (value) {
        setUserToken(value);
      }
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {userToken == null ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Restablecer" component={RestablecerPasswd} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registrar" component={RegistrarNewUsr} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Perfil" component={Perfil} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Configuraciones" component={CambiarPsswd} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Dietas" component={Dietas} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Datos" component={Data} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

this is my profile component , this is where i want to catch the data that i get from a http request including the token that i use to enter this screen :

```
const Perfil = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text>Datos del Usuario</Text>
          <Button title="Configuraciones" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Configuraciones')}/>
          <Button title="Mis Dietas" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dietas')}/>
          <Button title="Datos Semanales" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Datos')}/>
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

this is the way i get the token before enter the Perfil component screen:

```
const Login = ({navigation}) => {
  const INITIAL_TOKEN = 0;
  const token = useState(INITIAL_TOKEN);
  const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password,setPassword] = useState('');
  const onEndGetDatos = (payload) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('token', payload.data.token);
  };

  const sendDataL = () => {
    Axios.post('http://3.90.64.114/api/v1/web/login',{
        email,
        password
    }
    ).then(response => {
        onEndGetDatos(response);
    }).catch(err => {
        alert(err);
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token !== INITIAL_TOKEN) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('token', `${token}`);
    }
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView>
          <TextInput placeholder="Usuario(email)"
            onChangeText={email => setEmail(email)}
            keyboardType = 'email-address'
          />
          <TextInput placeholder="Contraseña" 
            secureTextEntry={true} 
            onChangeText={password => setPassword(password)}/>
          <Button title="Entrar" onPress={sendDataL}/>
          <Button title="Olvide mi Contraseña" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Restablecer')}/>
          <Button title="Soy Nuevo" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Registrar')}/>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is already getting the token from local storage when the app first renders here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value) => {
      if (value) {
        setUserToken(value);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

You can set a state value such as `userLoggedIn` to `true` and you can use that state value throughout your app.

When you want to logout, just clear the token value in local storage and set `userLoggedIn` state to `false`.

To pass this value to child components, you can use `props` or `useContext()` hook.